# Remove vice- versa entries in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have table having entries as

```
C1 C2
1   2
3   4
2   1
4   3
1   3
3   1
```

In my case I have to treat each occurrence of two as one pair irrespective of whether one number comes first or second i:e pairs like [1 2] and [2 1] are considered same. How do I keep only one pair of each occurrence in pandas, that is my result should only have:

```
C1 C2
1   2
3   4
1   3
```

Comment: This is not very clear: 'one pair of each occurrence', and I cannot deduce it from your desired output. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm treating 1 2 and  2 1 as same pair and I want to remove every second occurance of this pair